# UIButton losing target after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uibutton, target

I have(/had) a `UITextField` subclass which has a custom delete button as a rightView property.
This is working fine up until I rotate the device and then the button does not react anymore.
I changed my approach and 'cheated' a bit. Now I'm adding the `UIButton` on top of the `UITextField` in code. Which also works fine up until I rotate the device. I checked with backgroundColors if there are no other elements on top of the button.

I also tried removing the button and adding it again when the device rotates. It's visible but the action does not trigger. If I start my app in Portrait or in Landscape it works up until I rotate the device.

How I add the button:

```
if (!btn_delete)
{
    btn_delete = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 70, (tf_search.frame.size.height / 2) - 8, 17, 16)];
    [btn_delete setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cross_textfield"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_delete addTarget:self action:@selector(clearTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn_delete];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btn_delete];
}
else
{
    [btn_delete removeFromSuperview];
    btn_delete = nil;
}
```

Method `-(void)clearTextField:(UIButton*)sender` does not get called after rotation.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you should check frame of the self.view after rotation. your btw_delete became is outside of the frame rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked it with logs and thats not the case.

Comment: Check the `userInteraction` and try by adding fixed values to the button frame. If subview is outside the scope of main view the touches do not receive.

Comment: If you are testing app in Simulator then you can debug resizing issue from Debug->Color Blended Layers, by enabling this app will overlapped with different colors so you can easily get idea of your view position (If your button is going out of it's superView bound).

Comment: I was testing mostly on iPad but I followed your suggestion @Yuvrajsinh but I don't see anything wrong. After rotating the UIButton is still on the correct x, y value.

Comment: Have you check by giving clipsToBounds=YES for superview of your UIButton? to check Button is not out of it's superview. And if this is not the case then are you performing any code when rotation happens?

Comment: I added self.view.clipsToBounds = YES at viewDidLoad but that does not change anything.

Comment: Ok, I got a bit closer. There's something wrong with the repositioning of my elements after rotation. Sometimes you need some suggestions to start looking in the correct place, which I'm thankful for

Comment: Normally, what's on top is a function of the order in which you call addSubview.  I note that you are bringing btnDelete to the front explicitly in your code.  could it be that this explicit ordering is not being preserved thru rotation?  Is the text field transparent so the button could be visible even if it was behind after rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIButton was added to a UIViewController's UIView which was part of a UIView of another UIViewController. They all had clearColour as backgroundColor so the UIButton was still visible but not in the bounds of the superView.